# What does HClO2 aqueous solution decompose to in an open environment?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, decomposition

I looked up the decompositions of diluted $\ce{HClO2}$ aqueous solution (used in a disinfectant) to know if it is safe to use on some substances, such as metal, wood, leather or skin. However, the chain I found leading to $\ce{HClO4},$ which is a very strong acid.

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{5 HClO2 &→ 4 ClO2 + HCl + 2 H2O}\\
> \ce{4 HClO2 &→ 2 ClO2 + HClO3 + HCl + H2O}\\
> \ce{3 HClO2 &→ 2 HClO3 + HCl}\\
> \ce{2 HClO2 &→ 2 HOCl + HClO3}\\
> \ce{HClO2 &→ HCl + O2}
> \end{align}
> $$

Then there is

> $$\ce{3HClO3 → 2ClO2 + HClO4 + H2O}$$

(Source: *Inorganic Chemistry* by Garg and Singh [1], [Google book preview](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=XKxqCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT978&lpg=PT978&dq=4HClO2+%E2%86%92+2ClO2+%2B+HClO3+%2B+HCl+%2B+H2O&source=bl&ots=Gj8goScjH9&sig=ACfU3U1k1j-XIi2T6aJUnTGE3avo-dw6Mw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPluib5JToAhVnxosBHXfODEoQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=4HClO2%20%E2%86%92%202ClO2%20%2B%20HClO3%20%2B%20HCl%20%2B%20H2O&f=false))

The $\ce{HClO2}$ solution is diluted (I do not know the exact number, but maybe similar to mild bleach), sprayed to substances' surface, at room or body temperature.

Can the balances in this case lead to $\ce{HClO4}?$

On the other hand, $\ce{HCl}$ recombines to make $\ce{Cl2}$:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{HClO2 + 3 HCl &→ 2 Cl2 + 2H2O}\\
> \ce{HOCl + HCl &→ Cl2 + H2O}
> \end{align}
> $$

So, can the remaining $\ce{HCl}$ be concentrated enough to corrode metal or cause harms to skin?

From a consumer's point of view, $\ce{HClO2}$ seems to be a complete disinfectants for all of water, surface (by producing $\ce{HOCl}$), and air (by producing $\ce{ClO2}$). However, the issue left for concerns is the byproduct acids.

**Updates:** I found a list of patents about producing $\ce{HClO2}$ solutions to be used as disinfectants, which are likely the one I am talking about in this question. The patents claimed that the disinfectants are safe to human, can be used to clean food-processing utilities, and even as food additives. The exact reasons for the claims are not clear to me.

- https://patents.google.com/patent/US9516878B2/en
- https://patents.google.com/patent/AU2013205834B2/en
- https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2999490A2/en
- https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160106106A1/en
- https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160113282A1/en

#### References

1. Garg, R.; Singh, R. *Inorganic Chemistry*; McGraw-Hill Education: New Delhi, **2015**. ISBN 978-1-259-06285-8.

Comment: $\ce{HClO2}$ is a very disagreeable substance to use, as it quite easily produces plenty of unbearable and toxic gases like $\ce{ClO2}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ if the solution is made acidic. The danger of $\ce{HClO4}$ being formed in the solution may be considered as nearly negligible, compared to the danger of these gases.

Comment: [Is ChemiDay a reliable enough source (for inorganic reactions) to be cited on our site?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4255/41328) (spoiler: no, not really)

Comment: @andselisk Sorry, I'm new here. Can you refer me to a more suitable source for this site? Google show ChemiDay at the top of search page.

Comment: @Maurice How is it compared to other chlorine-based substances for disinfection? Maybe for disinfectant, those toxic gases are unavoidable. For example, HOCl and ClO2 aqueous solutions are also used as disinfectant.

Comment: @THN No need to apologize, the thing with ChemiDay is that they very rarely cite any sources, and even if they do, these are of questionable quality. You can use any source of information as long it's trustworthy and the claims are backed up by reputable sources, such as textbooks, articles, established databases etc.

Comment: @Maurice Actually I'm not making it, I asked from a consumer's point of view.

Comment: @Maurice I think you are right that toxic gases is the main issue, as I found some patents about HClO2 solution disinfectant which aim to reduce ClO2 production. Can you take a look and say about the if or why the solution can be used on human and household?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia on Chlorous acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorous_acid) to quote:

> The pure substance is unstable, disproportionating to hypochlorous acid (Cl oxidation state +1) and chloric acid (Cl oxidation state +5):
>
> $\ce{2 HClO2 → HClO + HClO3}$

Also, here are some interesting comments on the decomposition of chlorous acid in "[Kinetics and Mechanism of the Decomposition of Chlorous Acid](http://hopf.chem.brandeis.edu/pubs/pub293%20rep.pdf)" from J. Phys. Chem. A 2003, 107, pages 6966-6973, to quote:

> Of the many mechanistic models tested, the one that fit best included the following reactive intermediates: HOCl, Cl2O2, Cl2O3, •ClO, •OH. The stoichiometric ratio of ClO2 produced to Cl(III) consumed varies with pH and [Cl-]. Reaction of Cl2O3 with Cl(III) yields chlorate exclusively. Reaction of Cl2O3 with Cl- favors ClO2 over chlorate, but does not entirely exclude chlorate, because it is produced by hydrolysis of Cl2O2. Invoking Cl2O3 explains the variation in stoichiometric ratio as well as the maximum observed in the initial rate of ClO2 formation as a function of pH. The kinetics of chlorous acid decomposition cannot be quantitatively fit through the last stages of the reaction without postulating a first-order decomposition. Scission of chlorous acid to give short-lived hydroxyl and chlorine-(II) monoxide is a plausible route for this process [...]
>
> Several groups of investigators[5-7] have found
>   that in the absence of chloride ion the stoichiometry of the
>   decomposition of chlorous acid is given by reaction A:
>
> $\ce{4 HClO2 -> 2 ClO2 + ClO3- + Cl- + 2 H+ + H2O}$ (A)
>
> The stoichiometry of the decomposition of chlorous acid in the
>   presence of chloride ion is given by reaction B:
>
> $\ce{5 HClO2 -> 4 ClO2 + Cl- + H+ + 2 H2O}$  (B)

Also, to quote:

> Earlier studies,[9,18] in agreement with our present results, have also found the formation of more chlorate than predicted from reaction A. Reaction C
>
> $\ce{3 HClO2 -> 2 ClO3- + Cl- + 3 H+}$  (C)
>
> also plays a role in determining the stoichiometry at higher $\ce{HClO2}$ concentrations."

So, several intermediate products and depending on chloride presence possibly $\ce{ClO2}$, which is a problematic explosive and toxic gas, along with the strength of the $\ce{HClO2}$, which can introduce chlorate at higher chlorous acid concentrations.

Not a particularly good path to an acid as you are also inquiring about. As a disinfectant, the transient creation of the powerful disinfecting HOCl and associated radicals, may actually make it weaker, albeit more stable (considering end products) than hypochlorous acid, in my opinion.

[EDIT] To answer a comment question, as to whether is ClO2 safe, here is  a statement from the CDC, [Public Health Statement for Chlorine Dioxide and Chlorite](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/phs/phs.asp?id=580&tid=108), to quote:

> If you are exposed to chlorine dioxide or chlorite, many factors will determine whether you will be harmed. These factors include the dose (how much), the duration (how long), and how you come in contact with them. You must also consider any other chemicals you are exposed to and your age, sex, diet, family traits, lifestyle, and state of health.

Interestingly, ClO2, which is a stable free radical, has found commercial application as an [odor removal agent](https://closureclean.com/chlorine-dioxide-odor-removal/), likely due to its interaction with organics to create volatile organic chlorides (I would suspect that the presence of light would be catalytic). These VOCs are much more of a long-term health danger (as in carcinogenic), in my opinion.

Comment: OK, so by your quotes, it seems that in a solution, HClO2 will result in mainly ClO2, HCl, and HClO3, all nasty products.

Comment: I found a list of patents about HClO2 solution disinfectant (listed in the updated question). Can you take a look and say about the if or why the solution can be used on human and household?

Comment: Thank you for the expositions. I think I will stick to the good old NaOCl/HOCl solutions for now.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that the main decomposition product of HClO2 is ClO2. Commercial ClO2 generation systems typically incorporate a membrane used to separate the gas from the other components, such as the solids and undesirable side products. This helps create a highly pure solution of ClO2 in water.

Here are some examples:
https://www.dioxide.com/systems/chlorine-dioxide/
https://selectivemicro.com/about-us/#smtdiff

From a consumer's point of view, as you state, I would look into how the disinfectant solution is generated. Typically, you can react sodium chlorite (NaClO2) with an acid such as HCl or citric acid to generate HClO2 and therefore ClO2. Does the product use membrane technology to separate the gas? You mentioned HCl. Based on the reactions described, don't think concentrated HCl is a concern  (unless HCl is the acid used in the reaction). With Na ions present, you would more likely form NaCl.

Also "...water systems using chlorine dioxide for disinfection or oxidation must monitor their system for chlorine dioxide and chlorite." (https://www.evoqua.com/en/brands/municipal-services/Product%20Information%20Library/MSPOTABLEAP.pdf)

Comment: As you said that the production process of HClO2 is important. I found a patent about producing HClO2 solution for disinfectant (https://patents.google.com/patent/US9516878B2/en). Maybe this is the exact disinfectant that I am concerning. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: I found a list of patents about HClO2 solution disinfectant (listed in the updated question). Can you take a look and say about the if or why the solution can be used on human and household?